# why cast,convert donot work where round,floor works in the following case

Tags: mysql, database

I am a beginner to MySQL, i am trying to solve the following question

'''
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/average-population/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen
'''

where I need to round the average of all cities population, coming from the normal c++,c background I thought casting a decimal to int would round the integer but it's showing the following error

'''
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int)
from city' at line 1
'''
for the following code

'''
select cast(avg(population) as int)
from city;
'''
same error with convert as well.
could you please why this doesn't work where cast(25.5 as int) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use `CAST` or `CONVERT` function in mysql, the `int` is not a permitted type. Mysql has `SIGNED [INTEGER]` or `UNSIGNED [INTEGER]` for the same.

Reference: [MySQL CAST function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Tip: For rounding in MySQL you can also use [Round](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function.